# Javascript can't get contents of ASP.Net textbox when TinyMCE is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

I have a page that allows the user to send an email within our app.  I am trying to implement a "save draft" feature that captures what is in the To, CC, Subject, and Body fields. All the fields are ASP.Net textboxes, but the Body field has TinyMCE applied to it. I'm using this javascript to grab the contents of ASP.Net textboxes on a timer (set to 5 seconds here).

This occurs within an ASP.Net web form with a master page, but that is not the problem here.

This works great for all the fields except Body with the TinyMCE edit controls. This line:

body: $("#<%=txBody.ClientID%>").val()

returns ""

Any ideas on how to access the value/innerText/innerHTML when TinyMCE is applied?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="head">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txBody',
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: "bold italic forecolor",
        statusbar: false
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.setInterval(saveDraft, 5000);
        });

    function saveDraft() { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SaveDraft.aspx",
                data: ({
                    tofield: $("#<%=txTo.ClientID%>").val(),
                    ccfield: $("#<%=txCC.ClientID%>").val(),
                    subject: $("#<%=txSubject.ClientID%>").val(),
                    body: $("#<%=txBody.ClientID%>").val()
                }),
                success: function (response) {
                    var label = document.getElementById("<%=lbMsg.ClientID%>");
                    label.innerText = 'saving draft...';
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        label.innerText = '';
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });

        }
        }
  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: use the `getContent()` method of tinyMce  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Comment: Thanks!  `code`var contents = tinyMCE.get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txBody').getContent();`code` gets the contents correctly.  Some help with the syntax on the data: portion would be great. `code`...body: contents`code`    isn't working (not a javascript guy...)

Comment: This is the solution to getting the TinyMCE textbox contents into the JSON blob (also encoded for the subsequent Post):  body: encodeURI(tinyMCE.get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txBody').getContent())